# php upload data to mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c

I need to add data to my mysql database. When i run NSLOG on teamid it shows a 7 which is correct but when i run NSLOG on KTeamid it replies teamid. However nothing is being added to the actual database below is my xcode and below that is my php code. Can't seem to see why it doesn't work? Any suggestions / can you see the error?

```
-(void) postMessage:(NSString*) teamid withPlayerid:(NSString *) playerid withFixtureid:(NSString *) fixtureid withEventid:(NSString *) eventid withHalfid:(NSString *) halfid{

//check isnt receiving two anit paramters
if(teamid !=nil && playerid !=nil && fixtureid !=nil && eventid !=nil && halfid !=nil){

    NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kPostURL];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@",kTeamid, teamid]];
    //makes kname equal to name
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kPlayerid , playerid]];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@",kFixtureid, fixtureid]];
    //makes kname equal to name
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kEventid , eventid]];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@",kHalfid, halfid]];
    //makes kname equal to name

    [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@",teamid);
    NSLog(@"%@",kTeamid);


}
}

-(IBAction)prop1Button:(id)sender{
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// getting an NSString
NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"1 - Prop"];

 _textField3.text = myString;
[self postMessage: self.textField2.text withPlayerid:self.textField3.text withFixtureid:self.textField3.text withEventid:self.textField3.text withHalfid:self.textField3.text];
_textField2.text = nil;
_textField3.text = nil;
dropGoalCounter ++;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DoUpdateLabel" object:nil userInfo:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

Here is my php code for inserting into the database

```
<?php
include ("./inc/connect.inc.php");
$teamid = $_GET["teamid"];
$playerid = $_GET["playerid"];
$fixtureid = $_GET["fixtureid"];
$eventid = $_GET["eventid"];
$half = $_GET["halfid"];

$query = "INSERT INTO MatchEvent VALUES ('','$teamid','$playerid','$fixtureid','$eventid','$half')";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error("error"));

mysql_close();

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I realize is: 
Here you have a small k

```
[postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@",kTeamid, teamid]];
```

While here you use a capital K. Mabye just a typo?

```
NSLog(@"%@",KTeamid);
```

Edit: 
you keep mixing ? and & when you append data. Why? As far as I'm understanding this you need to use the ? symbol only for the first value you pass: www.URL.com?teamid=testTeamId
and from then on you need to use the & symbol to pass a new value:
www.URL.com?teamid=testTeamId&key2=value2&key3=value3

If this doesn't help could you post the URLString through NSLog when everything has been appended?

Comment: sorry that was just a type ive corrected that in my answer. any suggestions?